# Case when only executes ELSE statement

Tags: sql-server

I have never seen this happen before, but when I `SELECT` a `CASE WHEN` statement in SQL Server, it executes the `ELSE` statement. How is this possible? Is it because it cannot handle different kind of value types in the same column?

```
SELECT CASE WHEN len(birthDate)=4 THEN birthDate
            WHEN birthDate = '' THEN ''
            ELSE CONVERT(datetime, birthDate)
       END AS [birthDateConverted]
       ,[birthDate]
FROM BirthDayTable
```

The result looks like this:

```
birthDateConverted          birthDate
1951-01-01 00:00:00.000     1951
1936-06-19 00:00:00.000     June 19, 1936
1948-03-11 00:00:00.000     March 11, 1948
NULL
```

I want to have the following:

```
birthDateConverted          birthDate
1951                        1951
1936-06-19                  June 19, 1936
1948-03-11                  March 11, 1948
NULL
```

And I also do not understand why I get NULL when I specify ''. But this part is not as important as the first part, as I would like to have only the year when only a year is specified.

Comment: NULL because '' is invalid date format. Can you select len(birthDate) from BirthDayTable?

Comment: ISNULL would also work in this situation i.e. ISNULL(birthDate,'')

Comment: @mrPY look my answer I think your requirement will fulfil

Comment: keep the data type same in your case when statement. Either convert everything to datetime OR convert everything to varchar. Also if you try to compare different types, please make sure the comparison has same data types. This will give you the expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this first and then implement the logic accordingly in your query.
Replace @birthDate variable with the input string that you desire.

There is one more check that you can perform using ISDATE() function which checks if the entered string is a valid date and you can change your logic accordingly if required.

More information about isdate() function can be found [here](https://database.guide/isdate-examples-in-sql-server/)

```
DECLARE @birthDate varchar(20)=''
SET @birthDate='March 11, 1948'

SELECT CASE WHEN len(@birthDate)=4 THEN CONVERT(varchar, @birthDate)
        WHEN CONVERT(varchar,@birthDate) = '' THEN ''
        ELSE CONVERT(varchar,CONVERT(date, @birthDate))
   END AS [birthDateConverted]
```

Comment: This doesn't work, it outputs e.g. February 05, 1944 to Feb  5 1944 12:00AM

Comment: My apologies. I am editing my answer via which you can check if you get the expected output.

Comment: Works like a charm ;) Thank you Gaurav

Answer (score 0):

`NULL` is not equal to '' so, you can do instead :

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN len(birthDate) = 4 
             THEN birthDate
             WHEN birthDate IS NULL 
             THEN ''
             ELSE CONVERT(datetime, birthDate)
       END) AS [birthDateConverted],
       [birthDate]
FROM BirthDayTable;
```

However, `''` will implicit convert into datetime.

Comment: But the actual column is not NULL it is ''  and the important part is the date formatting for me, not the NULL values

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to store multiple types in one column which is not possible in SQL. So when the query executes on SQL Server it will type all the values on first read type.
In your case, your second conditions always fail due to comparing a null value with an empty string, in SQL you can achieve this through ISNULL(birthDate,'') = '' so when the value is null or empty it always returns true. 
So you can't set an empty string or date string with DateTime value your requirement is invalid.
I think you are looking for this it will format DateTime values as string

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN ISDATE(birthDate) = 1 
             THEN CONVERT(varchar, CONVERT(datetime,birthDate), 110)
             ELSE birthDate
        END) AS [birthDateConverted], [birthDate]
FROM    BirthDayTable;
```

Comment: This works well, but it still converts the date to january the first. I have added a solution myself.

Comment: You should vote me, I think I provided you the best solution just because I don't know your actual requirement that's why It's not your solution

Comment: Through convert varchar, there are multiple formats you can see it all, which are starting from 100 to 114. In your case, you can try 103 in place of 110

Comment: Thank you Adnan, but I cannot vote this as the complete answer as people will reference this question in the future. But for people who want only one field type (date) this is the neatest answer

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the following, which works for my case. Hopefully someone else can benefit from it too

```
  SELECT CASE WHEN len(birthDate)>4 
        THEN CONCAT(YEAR(birthDate), '-', RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(2), DATEPART(MONTH, (birthDate))),2), '-', 
             RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(2), DATEPART(DAY, (birthDate))),2)) 
        WHEN len(birthDate)=4 
        THEN CONVERT(nvarchar(255), birthDate)
        ELSE '' 
   END AS [birthDateConverted]
,[birthDate]
FROM BirthDayTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

A `CASE` will only return 1 datatype.
In your SQL that would return a DATETIME because of that convert.
And since '1951' is then implicitly casted to a DATETIME, it returns '1951-01-01 00:00:00.000'.

So let the `CASE` return a VARCHAR.

If you're using MS SQL Server 2012 or higher, then you could use [TRY_CONVERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql) to verify if the varchar can be converted to a date or datetime.

Because a TRY_CONVERT will return NULL when the conversion attempt fails.

**Example snippet:**

```
select *, 
 (case 
  when birthDate like '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]' then birthDate
  when birthDate like '%[0-9]%' and try_convert(date, birthDate) is not null 
  then convert(varchar(10), convert(date, birthDate), 20)
  else ''
  end) as birthDateConverted
from (values 
 (1,'1951'),
 (2,'June 19, 1936'),
 (3,'March 11, 1948'),
 (4,''),
 (5,null),
 (6,'ABCD')
) t(id, birthDate);
```

**Returns:**

```
id  birthDate      birthDateConverted
--  -------------- ------------------
1   1951           1951
2   June 19, 1936  1936-06-19
3   March 11, 1948 1948-03-11
4       
5   NULL    
6   ABCD
```